# how to implement upgrade in customer ui application, when i call Engine.Plan(LanchAction.UpdateReplace) it's not work

Tags: wix

how to implement upgrade in customer ui application, when i call Engine.Plan(LanchAction.UpdateReplace) it's not work, i  set already updatecode and add upgrade element

1.installed an old version
2.buid new version
3.run bootstrapper.exe update application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install and Burn will do an upgrade if the version is higher than any Bundles with the same UpgradeCode.

What you are doing is an inplace update where you install a newer version than the one you are running before anything has been installed.